# Many Threads in "wait" when using RestTemplate

Tags: spring, multithreading, tomcat, spring-boot, java-8

I'm having a problem with slowiness when many request come to my website, It starts to generate "Wait" threads, I've set up the rest template as a Bean

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
            .setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("service.configuration.http.http-request-timeout")))
            .setReadTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("service.configuration.http.http-request-timeout")))
            .requestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory())
            .build();
}
```

When i look for the process which is generating that problem i find HttpClient in wait.

Anybody knows what can i do to solve this problem?

I'm using **java8, apache tomcat, spring boot**

Comment: I had a similar issue and I solved it by using HttpClient as factory for resttemplate

Comment: You mean something like this: @Bean
 public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
     
     factory.setReadTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("service.configuration.http.http-request-timeout")));
     factory.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("service.configuration.http.http-request-timeout")));
     
  return new RestTemplate(factory);
 }

Comment: Nope. I used a different approach. If you want I can find and share my code

Comment: Please @AngeloImmediata. I'll apreciate it!

Comment: Why not use @Value annotations for retrieving properties?

Comment: I have the same problem, can you share how you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

In my past project I used this kind of configuration:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate()
{
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(); 
    factory.setHttpClient(httpClient());
    RestTemplate result = new RestTemplate(factory);
    return result;
}
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient()
{
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
    //Use a connection pool
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pcm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

    HttpClientBuilder hcb = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    //Close Idle connection after 5 seconds
    pcm.closeIdleConnections(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    //Specify all the timeouts in milli-seconds
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000).setSocketTimeout(5000).setConnectTimeout(5000).build();
    hcb.setDefaultRequestConfig(config);
    hcb.setConnectionManager(pcm).setConnectionManagerShared(true);
    // Check if proxy is required to connect to the final resource
    if (proxyEnable)
    {
        //If enabled.... configure it
        BasicCredentialsProvider credentialProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        AuthScope scope = new AuthScope(hostProxy, portProxy);
        if( StringUtils.hasText(usernameProxy) && StringUtils.hasText(passwordProxy) )
        {

            UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(usernameProxy, passwordProxy);
            credentialProvider.setCredentials(scope, credentials);
        }
        hcb.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialProvider).setRoutePlanner(proxyRoutePlanner);
    }
    //Use custom keepalive strategy
    if (cas != null)
    {
        hcb.setKeepAliveStrategy(cas);
    }
    httpClient = hcb.build();
    return httpClient;
}
```

Where `cas` is an instance of:

```
public class WsKeepAliveStrategy implements ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy
    {
        private Long timeout;

        @Override
        public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
        {
            return timeout;
        }

        public void setTimeout(Long timeout)
        {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

    }
```

In this way I could configure httpclient in order to use a connection pool, specify when to close the idle connection and specify the socket timeout, connection timeout, connection request timeout

By using this configuration I add no more issue

I hope it can be useful

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

Must be a case of missing timeout, should try to get the exact problem happening in your case, and change the setting causing that. Changing RequestFactory to another library may or may not solve that it all depends on the problem - so my advise is to identify it first. 
For example:
We faced similar issue that our thread was getting stuck in restTemplate so we took a thread dump which were like

```
    "pool-12-thread-1" #41 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f17a624e000 nid=0x3d runnable [0x00007f1738f96000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    - locked <0x00000000ebc7d888> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    - locked <0x00000000ebc7d8a0> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x00000000e94b9608> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
    - locked <0x00000000d57e5a30> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    - locked <0x00000000d57e5a30> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:84)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
```

It clearly show that the reason is missing timeout in read so we added

```
final SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(10_000);  // 10 sec as needed by us
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Similarly after you got the reason, add proper timeout

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](https://medium.com/@yannic.luyckx/resttemplate-and-connection-pool-617ebd924f68) explains why it happens.

> This configuration is inline with another Baeldung's article about rest template builder. It seems nice and clean but it hides a default PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with the defaultMaxPerRoute set to 5.
> What does this default max per route means? It means that only 5 simultaneous HTTP connections to the same host will be possible.

So you can configure RestTemplate to use a pooled implementation such as HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory with overridden `defaultMaxPerRoute`:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnManager = new 
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
poolingConnManager.setMaxTotal(50);
poolingConnManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
```